# Device position is getting reset on minimap in Indoor Navigation App

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, arcore

I am currently developing an AR application in Unity using ARCore for Android devices where I am using following c# script on a indicator cube to showcase current position of the user on a mini map

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;
using TMPro;

public class SetNavigationTarget : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private TMP_Dropdown navigationTargetDropDown;
    [SerializeField]
    private List<Target> navigationTargetObjects = new List<Target>();

    private NavMeshPath path; // current calculated path
    private LineRenderer line;// linerenderer to display path
    private Vector3 targetPosition = Vector3.zero; // current target position
    private bool lineToggle = false;
    private float elapsed = 0.0f;


    private void Start()
    {

        path = new NavMeshPath();
        line = transform.GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
        line.enabled = lineToggle;
        elapsed = 0.0f;
    }

    private void Update()
    {        
        elapsed += Time.deltaTime;
        if (lineToggle && targetPosition != Vector3.zero)
        {
            if(elapsed > 0.5f)
            {
                elapsed -= 0.5f;
                NavMesh.CalculatePath(transform.position, targetPosition, NavMesh.AllAreas, path);
                line.positionCount = path.corners.Length;
                line.SetPositions(path.corners);
            }
           // for (int i = 0; i < path.corners.Length - 1; i++)
            //    Debug.DrawLine(path.corners[i], path.corners[i + 1], Color.red);
        }
    }


    public void SetCurrentNavigationTarget(int selectedValue)
    {
        targetPosition = Vector3.zero;
        string selectedText = navigationTargetDropDown.options[selectedValue].text;
        Target currentTarget = navigationTargetObjects.Find(x => x.Name.Equals(selectedText));
        if(currentTarget != null)
        {
            targetPosition = currentTarget.PositionObject.transform.position;
        }
    }

    public void ToggleVisibility()
    {
        lineToggle = !lineToggle;
        line.enabled = lineToggle;
    }

}
```

but after moving certain distance the cube position is getting reset to few feet behind this error is not consistent but happening quite frequently

These are the error messages I managed to find from the android logcat

> 2023-01-28 11:06:04.224 7591 7703 Error native E0000 00:00:1674884164.224372    7703 sbr_action_state.cc:220] Failed to obtain consistent ADF to VIO transformation.

> 2023-01-28 11:06:03.819 7591 7703 Error native E0000 00:00:1674884163.819882    7703 sbr_action_state.cc:85] FAILED_PRECONDITION: Re-evaluation failed and the number of corrupted adf transform VIO frames does not reach the reset threshold.

> 2023-01-28 11:05:46.433 7591 7703 Error native E0000 00:00:1674884146.433859    7703 sbr_action_state.cc:220] 2 consistent ADF to VIO transformation from MLE are required to initialize this variable in VIO. Current value is 1.

Any help is appreciated